# GPS sign doesn't go away when I kill all apps

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an app that uses GPS location. However I got a feedback that closing the app doesn't stop GPS. A user complained about iOS 7.1 saying that before iOS update the app was not doing that. Since I didn't change code, I wonder if I have to in order to satisfy iOS7.1 needs.

Here is what I do:

```
CLLocationManager *_lm;

- (void)mode:(LocatorMode)mode
{
    NSLog(@"Location mode: %d", mode);

    switch (mode) {
        case lmBackground:
            [_lm stopUpdatingLocation];
            [_lm startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
            break;

        default:
            [_lm stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
            [_lm startUpdatingLocation];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[Locator defaultLocator] mode:lmPrecise];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[Locator defaultLocator] mode:lmBackground];
}
```

Here is a screenshot I've made. Notice that there is no single app running and yet GPS sign is lit (a little arrow in top right corner).

[image]

Comment: there are a number of iOS services that can cause GPS to turn on. What evidence do you have that it's your app doing it?

Comment: I have no evidence. According to the user, before iOS7.1 update, the sign would go away  once app is closed (in my experience in 5-10 seconds). I have just deleted my app from the device to make sure it's not me that doing that. My concern is that if I have to change the way how I track location when app is active. I haven't found any info that indicated I had to change anything compared to iOS7.0-. There seems to be no way for me to know if I am doing the right thing. Although I will follow on your advice and see what I can disable in Location settings.

Comment: You can check which device is activating the icon in the privacy settings.